# ConnectionError: Error 2 connected to unix socket in Python/Django Redis

Tags: python, django, sockets, unix, redis

I'm trying to run a django project locally on a brand new Mac. It was working up until yesterday, and I have no clue what happened, but all of a sudden I started getting Redis errors.

I can load pages that don't query the database, but once I try to do a search, which relies partly on Redis, it doesn't work.

Any ideas? here is the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/dlitwak/mozio/dotcloud/demo/search/views.py", line 391, in results
    cache.setDistanceAndDuration(distance, time, request.user.username)
  File "/Users/dlitwak/mozio/dotcloud/demo/cache.py", line 305, in setDistanceAndDuration
    self.cache.set(key, value, 1800)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis_cache/cache.py", line 218, in set
    result = self._set(key, pickle.dumps(value), int(timeout), client, _add_only)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis_cache/cache.py", line 199, in _set
    return client.setex(key, value, timeout)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1221, in setex
    return self.execute_command('SETEX', name, time, value)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 338, in execute_command
    connection.send_command(*args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 287, in send_command
    self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 269, in send_packed_command
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 217, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
ConnectionError: Error 2 connecting to unix socket: 127.0.0.1. No such file or directory.
```

We are running MYSQL. I can access the db through the terminal, so I don't think it's a DB access problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is because Django cannot connect to the database, and redis is throwing the error.
And since you can load pages without db, seems like it’s the case.

Comment: You don't specify which database you are using, but if its postgres i recommend you go with http://postgresapp.com/ for the easiest way to get it up and working.

Comment: We definetely need more information to help you debug this, how are you running redis? and your database?

Comment: We are using MYSQL. It is not a db problem, as we have other pages that use the DB that are retrieving their info just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we finally got it to work.

For some reason Redis is no longer being started automatically and is not running in the background.

I'm working on a Mac, and it previously did this automatically when I was running on Ubuntu. The solution was to run "redis-server" in a separate terminal window.

We are still trying to figure out how to make it start automatically, or why it stopped in the first place, but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

If your using a Mac, using the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) package manager is probably the best way to install and manage Redis. Once Homebrew is installed simply, `brew install redis` on the command line.

After it's installed you can set it up to run automatically on startup:

`ln -sfv /usr/local/opts/redis/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Then to run it now:

`launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist`